# HTMLElement.append does not append - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What are some possible reasons that this code could not append the  tag to the #abcde div?

```
    var div = $('#abcde');
                console.log(div);
                div.append('<h1>Hi</h1>');
```

console.log shows:

```
b.fn.b.init[0]
context: document
selector: "#abcde"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

HTML elements inspection:

```
<div class="km-scroll-container" style="-webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;">
    <h1 style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" class="pageTitle" id="singleClientHeading">Jacques Johnson</h1>
    <div class="km-listview-wrapper"><ul class="listView km-widget km-listview km-list km-listinset" data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
        <li>
            <label class="question">OID</label><label class="right_column_single_client" id="oid">2143.16</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="question">NHI</label><label class="right_column_single_client" id="nhi">HGC4526</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="question">Dwelling</label><label class="right_column_single_client" id="dwelling">TFR</label>
        </li>
    </ul></div>
    <div id="abcde"></div> /////////////###################see div here to append to, did not work





    <!--<ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class=" listView km-widget km-listview km-list km-listinset">
            <li><label class="km-listview-label question">OID</label></li>
            <li><label class="km-listview-label" style="height: 2.5em; width:100%;">
                <label id="oid" style="left:0; width:100%;"></label>
            </label></li>
        </ul>
        <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class="listView km-widget km-listview km-list km-listinset">
            <li><label class="km-listview-label question">NHI</label></li>
            <li><label class="km-listview-label" style="height: 2.5em; width:100%;">
                <label id="nhi" style="left:0; width:100%;"></label>
            </label></li>
        </ul>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class="listView km-widget km-listview km-list km-listinset">
            <li><label class="km-listview-label question">Location</label></li>
            <li><label class="km-listview-label" style="height: 2.5em; width:100%;">
                <label id="dwelling" style="left:0; width:100%;"></label>
            </label></li>
        </ul>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class="listView km-widget km-listview km-list km-listinset">
            <li><label class="km-listview-label question">Observations</label></li>
            <li><label class="km-listview-label" style="height: 2.5em; width:100%;">
                <select style="left:0; width:100%;" id="allObservationsDropDown" onchange="if (typeof(this.selectedIndex) != undefined) {navigateToObservation(); this.blur();}"  onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;"></select>
            </label></li>
        </ul>-->




    <div class="km-listview-wrapper"><ul id="" data-role="listview" data-style="inset" class="listView km-widget km-listview km-list km-listinset">
            <li><label class="km-listview-label question">Perform Observation</label></li>
            <li><label class="km-listview-label" style="height: 2.5em; width:100%;">
                <select style="left:0; width:100%;" id="allObservationsDropDown" onchange="if (typeof(this.selectedIndex) != undefined) {navigateToObservation(true); this.blur();}" onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;"><option value="chooseO" selected="true" disabled="true">Choose observation...</option><option value="GLASGOW">Glasgow Coma Scale</option><option value="MO">Mobile Observation</option><option value="O">Observation</option></select>
            </label></li>
        </ul></div>









    <!--<ul class="listView" data-role="listview" data-style="inset">
        <li>
            <label class="question">Observations
                <br/>
            </label>
            <select id="allObservationsDropDown" onchange="if (typeof(this.selectedIndex) != undefined) {navigateToObservation(true); this.blur();}"  onfocus="this.selectedIndex = -1;"></select>
        </li>
    </ul>-->


</div>
```

I have used this technique in the pas and it worked. Is something wrong with my html page? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is the code executing after the document ready event?

Comment: @OJay That was the problem, thanks. If you like you can write than as an answer and I will mark as correct. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to select an element on the HTML page, that element must exist on the page when the code runs, and since the browsers reads the page from top to bottom, if it gets to a script in the `head` that tries to access an element in the `body` before it has read/rendered the `body`, it won't find it). There is two main ways to do this, either put your javascript at the bottom of the page, or make sure that you code is wrapped in the document ready jQuery wrapper.

This can be done a couple of ways in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Put code here to run after the DOM is loaded
});
```

or

```
$(function(){
    //Put code here to run after the DOM is loaded
});
```

Now as an additional point, if you try to select an element on the page, and it is not there, you will not get an error, and the return value will still be something (its the jQuery wrapper object). So in your case, why you were seeing what you were see on the console was because you outputted the jQuery object (which has properties of `context` and `selector`, even if nothing is found). There is a quick test to see if jQuery has got an/any element/s and that is check the `length`

i.e.

```
var div = $('#abcde');
console.log(div); //This will log the jQuery wrapper object,
                  //doesn't mean that it has actually found element #abcde
```

checking the length will give you how many elements jQuery has found that match your selector

```
var div = $('#abcde');
console.log(div.length); //If this logs 0, you haven't got the element
```